# Separate public / private signature for method

Tags: typescript

If I have a method like this:

```
private render(componentName: string)
```

is there a way to add a public signature for this that only allows certain specific strings like

```
public render(componentName: "Avatar" | "Message" | "Link")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add two overloads, one for the public interface of the method, and one for the implementation signature of the method.

The implementation signature is not callable from anywhere it is just used for the types of the parameters inside the implementation:

```
class Cls {
    public render(componentName: "Avatar" | "Message" | "Link"): void
    public render(componentName: string) {
        componentName = "" // componentName is string 
    }
    m() {
        this.render("Avatar") // ok 
        this.render("Avatar_") // err
    }

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIwN4ChpugBwK4CMQEthoAnAUwDsATU4gCmAHsBbDB8igFwDkwnSAuaACIAggDcwHMMSHQAPsICypKGADmpWQqEAZfOQDWQgJSCxDfJVTpseQiQrU6jFm048+giB2L61x6BR0YOgXVnZybl5SaABeYVkAekTQ5nD3aOh8GG9fcjVoazQAXyLoJloAoJC0DgALbIA6MioaWlEJKRkA5OgGA0Ka2oaIZsc2jslpAH0TaF6aYjLS5GKgA)

Note: There is no way to have different accessibility modifiers for different overloads of the same method in TS. You could have different methods instead.

```
class Cls {
    public render(componentName: "Avatar" | "Message" | "Link"): void {
        this.renderInternal(componentName)
    }
    private renderInternal(componentName: string) {
        componentName = "" // componentName is string 
    }
    m() {
        this.render("Avatar") // ok 
        this.renderInternal("Avatar_") // ok
    }

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIwN4ChpugBwK4CMQEthoAnAUwDsATU4gCmAHsBbDB8igFwDkwnSAuaACIAggDcwHMMSHQAPsICypKGADmpWQqEAZfOQDWQgJSCxDfJWgp0t6BwAW+CADoyVGgElyHGuTAg9Mys7D48fMao6AC+UWgYxPgSviQU1MTevsT+gYwsbJzhAtAQHInkasbWcXZ5IYW8pNAAvMKyAPTt0HUFYY3QziVl+mrQNbG2TLRVNnZojs5uaTS0osnSJtCd0AwGY3PzTq7u6Zl+AaviktIA+pvbu+PIyNFAA)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to have overloaded signatures with different access modifiers, but you can achieve the desired result using an interface:

```
interface IFoo {
    render(componentName: "Avatar" | "Message" | "Link"): void;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    public render(componentName: string): void {
        // ...
    }
}

const foo: IFoo = new Foo();
foo.render("Message"); // OK
foo.render("unto Caesar that which is Caesar's"); // error
```

To avoid code duplication when `Foo` has other members, the `IFoo` interface can be derived from `Foo` automatically:

```
type IFoo = Omit<Foo, 'render'> & {
    render(componentName: "Avatar" | "Message" | "Link"): void;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgYgewVAvFA8gWwJbADyIIA0UA5AE4QB2AJhOaQHxQBkUA3gFBQ9SW30AFAGMEmMAirVgAOQCGmCAC4oAIgCCANznA55VVAA+agLIQAzubkBzCAeOqAMtioBrVQEoVmhNhoBuTgBfTk5hABs5SyhCKGxxcIhFKmBzWFiuXigwAFcAI3DsYT5qOnIRMQkpFPlFFXNgchdrLygfPw5uLN4Aeh6oADohrp4QrNyCoqg8vUFW9ppO7qhgAAtscwH+MsFVGf0PQKyQkLDJBqgAMyQVeCRUKCkAdxikOcDrhC3SoVUzSxsdkOUD6GAA0pxPt8BOVVDkUsgAMJyCx6FarHRQJ7rYSrOJpZGohjmTz+EH9ejkBDkSFIAb7d7k8GcIA)

Comment: This approach is problematic because it relies on using an a type annotation, here `: IFoo`, to work. With any type, we can reduce the availability of members by accessing through a reference that's typed as something more restrictive but that isn't a solution.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It is not unusual in object-oriented languages to write a class which is only meant to be used externally via a particular interface. If the module exports the interface and a way of constructing the class, but does not export the class itself, then external code will not be able to downcast to the class type itself in order to use the wider signature.

Comment: Well, that would require a factory, which isn't suggested here. Factories have many advantages no doubt, but it seems to be out of scope.